Why won't my aerodynamics neural network converge?
I am training a neural network to predict the aerodynamic properties of an airfoil given 6 shape parameters, the angle of attack, and the Reynolds number. I have scraped about 120MB of training data in a CSV file. I am using JAX with Equinox as my neural network framework.
Here is my model definition:
import equinox as eqx

class SurrogateModel(eqx.Module):
    
    layers: list
        
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size, width_size, depth, activation, key):
        keys = jax.random.split(key, depth + 2)
        
        input_key = keys[0]
        output_key = keys[-1]
        hidden_keys = keys[1:-1]
        
        input_layer = eqx.nn.Linear(in_size, width_size, key=input_key)
        output_layer = eqx.nn.Linear(width_size, out_size, key=output_key)
        
        #Make Reynolds number on log10 scale
        @jax.jit
        def normalize_reynolds_number(x):
            Re = x[-1]
            Re = jnp.log10(Re)
            
            return jnp.hstack((x[:-1], Re))
            
        
        self.layers = [
            normalize_reynolds_number,
            jax.nn.standardize, #Standardize -1 to 1
            input_layer,
            activation
        ]
        for key in hidden_keys:
            self.layers.append(eqx.nn.Linear(width_size, width_size, key=key))
            self.layers.append(activation)
            
        self.layers.append(output_layer)
        
    def __call__(self, x):
                
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x)

        return x
        

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)

model = SurrogateModel(
    in_size=len(input_labels),
    out_size=len(output_labels),
    width_size=64,
    depth=4,
    activation=jax.nn.silu,
    key=key
)

The number of input labels are 8 and there is only one out label (which is the coefficient of lift).
I am using the Adam optimizer with stock parameters. My batch size is 200 and learning rate is 1e-3.
I am using simple MSE loss to compare the model prediction with my training data. However, when I train my model for a long time, the loss slowly falls but fails to learn any pattern. At a certain level of loss, it stops converging entirely. Here is a graph with some example data showing the predicted loss versus the ground truth for lift versus angle-of-attack:

How to fix my model?
I've tried multiple strategies such as standardizing my data around zero mean, using SiLU instead of Tanh (which made my model return the same output regardless of input), putting Reynolds number, which is over 10^5 times the value of the other inputs, on a log scale, and using the Adam optimizer. I'm still confused about whether I have too few or too many neurons for the task.
